# Featherlight gallery Previous Next span title

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I managed to place Featherlight Gallery on my website, I just can't seem to find where to change the "span title" on the previous/next buttons.
My site is in spanish, i want it to be "anterior/siguiente"
I already tried with the featherlight.gallery.min.js and find where "previous" or "next" and change it, but that breaks the code and doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported out of the box, sorry. PR welcome.

In the meantime, you can use Javascript in an `afterOpen` callback to modify them.

Comment: Thank you Marc
you think is it possible to eliminate/not show the span title? That could work for what i need as well.

Comment: Showing the title on hover is the standard behavior in most browsers, I don't think it can be overriden.

Comment: Thanks again Marc, my question was more like "where to eliminate the span title instruction, if the element is not there, it does not shows up, and no "previous/next" title.